# How to change the font type of y-axis in R

Tags: r, fonts

After spending quite a bit of time googling around, i was able to change the font of my barplot x-axis labels to italic and now i realize that the font of the y-axis scale is also changed. I can't quite workout how to change the font of barplot x-axis labels and keep the y-axis scale as they are. Here is my code and the generated plot

```
string1 = "Percent "
string2 = " homologous lincRNA loci identified"
new = paste0(string1, species, string2) 
barplot(plot, col = "blue",
        ylab = new, ylim = c(0, max(plot)*1.15),
        font=3, las = 2)                
text(bargraph,plot,labels = plot,pos=3,cex=.8)
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: you'll have to turn off the axis in barplot, and add one manually with axis()

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it and i am answering myself so that other people can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = "Percent "
string2 = " homologous lincRNA loci identified"
new = paste0(string1, species, string2) 
barplot(plot, col = "blue",
        ylab = new, ylim = c(0, max(plot)*1.15),
        font=3, yaxt = "n", las = 2)
axis(2)                
text(bargraph,plot,labels = plot,pos=3,cex=.8)
```

[image]